# We are putting speakers in the trees in parks and need some design suggestions for systems

Tags: audio, design, system

Sounds Art project in the Parks.

We are putting speakers in the trees in parks and need some design suggestions for systems.

We are putting 3 x out door speakers in seprate trees in the park and we are wondering what equipment we need in order to control the 3 x speakers wirelessly, have them on seprate channels/ playlists.

We want a user friendly interface to update and change songs, announsments...

The speakers and the control system would be a few 100 yards away from each other. Also no power in the trees.

Any design help, ideas or suggestions would be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have no power in the trees, how are you going to make the speakers go?  If you are running a signal wire to each speaker, then why does it need to be wireless?  Is it simply that you want to be able to turn on and control volume and source of the amps wirelessly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you may have to use XBee wireless modules hooked up to Sparkfun MP3 Triggers.  This will only deal with pre-recorded audio.

Here are some links:
MP3 TRigger: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11029

Xbee: https://www.sparkfun.com/pages/xbee_guide

If you're unfamiliar with these there may be a bit of a learning curve but I once looked into wireless audio and this ended up being the best way as far as I found.

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually addresses the situation.  Based on the description, it appears that the speakers themselves will be unpowered and receive a powered signal from an amp at the control system.  My guess is that the wireless control needs to be the ability to remotely turn on the amps and send signal to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cell phones and tablets, you can just connect everything via wlan and start e.g. the vlc app that can stream mic input to a vlc player in the same wlan.

Comment: Can you rework your answer?  It isn't clear what you are trying to say.